# Interpreting SPSS output for mixed linear models - there are zero values in estimates of fixed effect

Tags: mixed-model, spss

I need help in interpreting the output for mixed linear model.The estimates of fixed effect shows the parameters of my level 1 predictor variables, but there are some zero values, and i'm not sure why or how to interpret it. Could it be due to lack of data points in ITEM16? Here's a snapshot of the output..

```
Parameter   Estimate    Std. Error  df  t   Sig.    95% Confidence Interval 
                        Lower Bound Upper Bound
Intercept   .184285 .016181 40.209  11.389  .000    .151588 .216982
[ITEM=1]    -.033855    .008585 29812.714   -3.944  .000    -.050681    -.017029
[ITEM=2]    -.020130    .008915 29812.824   -2.258  .024    -.037603    -.002657
[ITEM=3]    -.064286    .008792 29814.834   -7.312  .000    -.081519    -.047053
[ITEM=4]    -.077827    .009920 29817.388   -7.846  .000    -.097270    -.058384
[ITEM=5]    -.040264    .011120 29804.602   -3.621  .000    -.062061    -.018468
[ITEM=6]    -.031131    .008790 29815.299   -3.542  .000    -.048359    -.013903
[ITEM=7]    -.037671    .010160 29809.248   -3.708  .000    -.057585    -.017757
[ITEM=8]    -.023466    .010947 29806.310   -2.143  .032    -.044923    -.002008
[ITEMC=9]   -.025810    .011665 29807.427   -2.213  .027    -.048673    -.002947
[ITEM=10]   -.004509    .011803 29805.702   -.382   .702    -.027643    .018626
[ITEM=11]   -.073471    .009903 29816.904   -7.419  .000    -.092881    -.054061
[ITEM=12]   -.059247    .010095 29806.327   -5.869  .000    -.079033    -.039460
[ITEM=13]   -.038357    .014345 29810.276   -2.674  .008    -.066474    -.010240
[ITEM=14]   -.032134    .013288 29807.876   -2.418  .016    -.058178    -.006089
[ITEM=15]   -.046073    .010736 29808.929   -4.291  .000    -.067116    -.025029
[ITEM=16]   0   0   .   .   .   .   .
[...}.....
...
...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like ITEM is a categorical factor variable, in which case the model is parameterized with a dummy or indicator variable for each distinct value of it, and if there is a fixed intercept in the model, the last one of these will be redundant or linearly dependent on the prior ones. That gets aliased to 0 in the formation of the generalized inverse formed during estimation. This is to be expected and does not indicate a problem.

If you have additional factor variables you'll see similar situations for them, and for interactions involving factors you'll generally see multiple parameters aliased to 0.